# Does Wonder Woman have a no kill rule?

Tags: dc, wonder-woman

Like her teammates Batman and Superman, does Wonder Woman also have a no-kill rule?

As she certainly did kill a lot of German soldiers in the WW 2017 movie, my question is primarily towards her comic book and/or animated universe version.

*PS: Not counting the Flashpoint version as in it, she was basically an evil version.*

Comment: The dupe contains multiple examples of her killing mortals. She does it reluctantly but she doesn't have a specific "I don't kill" rule that she's breaking when she does it.

Comment: Cool. Thanks @Valorum. That should answer my question.